# CUDA 4.0 Peer to Peer Access confusion

Tags: cuda

I have two questions related to CUDA 4.0 Peer access:

1. Is there any way I could copy data like from `GPU#0 ---> GPU#1 ---> GPU#2 ---> GPU#3`. Presently in my code it works fine when I use just two GPUs at a time, but fails when I check peer access on a third GPU using `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer`. So, the following works - 
   `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&flag_01, dev0, dev1)`, but when I have two such statements:
   `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&flag_01, dev0, dev1)` and `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&flag_12, dev1, dev2)`, the later fails (0 is returned to the flag_12 variable).
2. Would it work only for GPUs connected via a common PCIe OR is Peer copy dependent upon the underlying PCIe interconnection? I do not understand PCIe, but upon doing nvidia-smi I see that the PCIe buses of the GPUs are 2, 3, 83 and 84.

The testbed is a dual socket 6 core Intel Westmere, with 4 GPUs - Nvidia Tesla C2050.

EDIT:
Bandwidthtest between HtoD and DtoH, and SimpleP2P results between two GPUs (DtoD):
[image]

Comment: What error do you get?  Note that you enable peer access with `cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess()`, not `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer` -- the latter is for querying.

Comment: I am firstly checking whether two devices could be a peer by `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer`, and then enabling peer access by `cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess()`. `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer` is returning an error when I try to check, say devices 1,2 after checking 0,1....when I just stick to two devices everything is fine, but when I include more devices, I get flagged out.

Comment: I just found your post here: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=206809  From your deviceQuery results it appears you have only one GPU in your system.

Comment: No this is a different problem (related to simpleP2P not running on one of the machines), I would check the specific error code and report back.

Comment: `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&can_access_peer_0_2, device#0, device#2)` is returning false, and my program is exiting. There are all total 5 GPUs in my system, and I am excluding one, so the device enum goes like {0,2,3,4}...I think this function only returns a 1 in success or 0 for failure.

Comment: The return value is a cudaError_t, not a bool.  You are talking about the first parameter, which writes an int 0 or 1.  You still haven't answered WHAT the error code returned is.  While you are at it, what type of GPUs are in your system, and what OS are you running, and is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Sayan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2046/discussion-between-harrism-and-sayan)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem.  From an upcoming NVIDIA document:

NVIDIA GPUs are designed to take full advantage of the PCI-e Gen2 standard, including the Peer-to-Peer communication, but the IOH chipset does not support the full PCI-e Gen2 specification for P2P communication with other IOH chipsets

The cudaPeerEnable() API call will return an error code if the application tries to establish a P2P relationship between two GPUs that would require P2P communication over QPI.  The cudaMemcopy() function for P2P Direct Transfers automatically falls back to using a Device-to-Host-to-Device path, but there is no automatic fallback for P2P Direct Access (P2P load/store instructions in device code).

One known example system is the HP Z800 workstation with dual IOH chipsets which can run the simpleP2P example, but bandwidth is very low (100s of MB/s instead of several GB/s) because of the fallback path.

NVIDIA is investigating whether GPU P2P across QPI can be supported by adding functionality to future GPU architectures.

Reference: Intel® 5520 Chipset and Intel® 5500 Chipset Datasheet, Table 7-4: Inbound Memory Address Decoding: 
“The IOH does not support non-contiguous byte enables from PCI Express for remote peer-to-peer MMIO transactions. This is an additional restriction over the PCI Express standard requirements to prevent incompatibility with Intel QuickPath Interconnect”.  -- http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/321328.pdf

In general we advise building multi-GPU workstations and clusters that have all PCI-express slots intended for GPUs connected to a single IOH.

Comment: I noticed that even then, bandwidth between GPUs connected via a single IOH is quite less. Another colleague of mine also confirmed the same. Please refer to the graph in the update section of the question above. I am just running the simpleP2P program against varying data sizes....

Comment: @harrism Please tell me, at this the moment, is this problem (GPU1 <-> CPU1 <-> QPI / HT <-> CPU2 <-> GPU2) solved in Kepler CC3.0 (3.5) and CUDA5.5?