# Can I use Quadro K4000 and K2000 for GPUDirect v2 Peer-to-peer (P2P) communictation?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I use:

- **Single CPU** [(Intel Core i7-4820K Ivy Bridge-E)](http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/77781/Intel-Core-i7-4820K-Processor-10M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) 40 Lanes of PCIe 3.0 + MotherBoard MSI X79A-GD65 (8D)
- WindowsServer 2012, MSVS 2012 + CUDA 5.5 and compiled as **64-bit application**
- GPUs nVidia **Quadro K4000 and K2000**
- All Quadros in **TCC-mode** (Tesla Compute Cluster)
- nVidia Video Driver 332.50

simpleP2P-test shown that, all Quadros K4000 and K4000 - IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P), but Peer-to-Peer (P2P) access - Quadro K4000 (GPU0) <-> Quadro K2000 (GPU1) : No.

Can I use Quadro K4000 and K2000 for [GPUDirect v2 Peer-to-peer (P2P) communication](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect)?

> [C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA
>   Samples\v5.5\0_Simple\simpleP2P../../bi
>   n/win64/Release/simpleP2P.exe] - Starting... Checking for multiple
>   GPUs... CUDA-capable device count: 3
>
> > GPU0 = "   Quadro K4000" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> >
> > GPU1 = "   Quadro K2000" IS  capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
> >
> > GPU2 = " GeForce GT 640" NOT capable of Peer-to-Peer (P2P)
>
> Checking GPU(s) for support of peer to peer memory access...
>
> > Peer-to-Peer (P2P) access from Quadro K4000 (GPU0) -> Quadro K2000 (GPU1) : No
> >
> > Peer-to-Peer (P2P) access from Quadro K2000 (GPU1) -> Quadro K4000 (GPU0) : No
>
> Two or more SM 2.0 class GPUs are required for C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA
>   Corporation \CUDA
>   Samples\v5.5\0_Simple\simpleP2P../../bin/win64/Release/simpleP2P.exe
>   to r un. Support for UVA requires a GPU with SM 2.0 capabilities. Peer
>   to Peer access is not available between GPU0 <-> GPU1, waiving test.

Quadros in TCC-mode:

```
nvidia-smi.exe"
Tue Mar 11 12:43:05 2014
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 5.320.57   Driver Version: 320.57         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K2000        TCC  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   30C    P8    N/A /  N/A |        6MB /  2047MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GT 640     WDDM  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   32C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     2016MB /  2047MB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Quadro K4000        TCC  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   36C    P8    10W /  87W |        8MB /  3071MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1            Not Supported                                               |
```

In the documentation said that: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect

> **GPUDirect** eliminates unnecessary system memory copies, dramatically
>   lowers CPU overhead, and reduces latency, resulting in significant
>   performance improvements in data transfer times for applications
>   running on NVIDIA Tesla™ **and Quadro™ products.**

More detailed specifications of Quadros there, but there are only about [GPUDirect For Video](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect), and nothing about P2P: http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/line_card/6660-nv-prographicssolutions-linecard-july13-final-lr.pdf

About PCIe bus:

```
nvidia-smi -q
GPU 0000:01:00.0
    Product Name                    : Quadro K2000
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x01
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x0FFE10DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:01:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x094C10DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : 2
                Current             : 1
            Link Width
                Max                 : 16x
                Current             : 8x
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 2047 MiB
        Used                        : 6 MiB
        Free                        : 2041 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : 256 MiB
        Used                        : 2 MiB
        Free                        : 254 MiB
    Compute Mode                    : Default
...

GPU 0000:02:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GT 640
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x02
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x0FC110DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:02:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x8A921462
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
            Link Width
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A

...

GPU 0000:03:00.0
    Product Name                    : Quadro K4000
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x03
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x11FA10DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:03:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x097C10DE
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : 2
                Current             : 1
            Link Width
                Max                 : 16x
                Current             : 16x
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 3071 MiB
        Used                        : 8 MiB
        Free                        : 3063 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : 256 MiB
        Used                        : 2 MiB
        Free                        : 254 MiB
    Compute Mode                    : Default
```

Can I use GPUDirect v2 P2P with Quadros, and if I can, then in which of these?
Should be size of the BAR1 is equal to the size of GPU-RAM to be able to use P2P?

**UPDATE 11.03.2014 23:16**:

1. I **can't use P2P Direct Transfers** - I transfered random generated data by using `cudaMemcpy(gpu_ptr1, gpu_ptr0, cudaMemcpyDefault);` successfully with 3 GB/sec on PCIe-gen2 8x (4 GB/sec theoretically), but function copies through the host - In VisualProfiler Context1(DtoH) and Context2(HtoD).
2. I **can't use P2P Direct Access** by using `__global__ Kernel(char *dst, char *src, size_t size) { int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; dst[idx] = src[idx]; }` - I get an error when use function `cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess()` and get `0` when using `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer()`

Comment: Might depend on the chipset and you might experience this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6935100/1938163 . There's no mention of this being fixed in CUDA 5.5 so I'm not excluding it

Comment: @David Kernin  Yes GPU0<->QPI/HT<->GPU1 not solved. But here I use single CPU with only one IOH, without QPI connection between GPUs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's related with your problem, but note this:

```
    GPU Link Info
        PCIe Generation
            Max                 : 2
            Current             : 1
        Link Width
            Max                 : 16x
            Current             : 8x
```

and this:

```
        PCIe Generation
            Max                 : 2
            Current             : 1
        Link Width
            Max                 : 16x
            Current             : 16x
```

that is, your PCIe links have been demoted from 2.0 (5 GT/s) to 1.0 (2.5 GT/s) and on one card from 16x to 8x... it's very possible that this is a problem for GPU direct too, but for sure it's not what you want, in order to squeeze all the performance from your PCIe (on one card you're getting 25% of the theoretical, 50% on the other one).

I have found that it's important the order where the card are put on the mothorboard; overheating can lead to downgrade of the buses too, or dust... planets alignment too probably....

EDIT: I didn't know that TCC was mandatory for GPU direct to work, so the following is not valid.

<strike>First of all I'd try to remove the display card and see if using only the two quadro cards you get all PCIe 2.0/16x, and whether in this case GPU direct starts working or not.</strike>

EDIT: from your additional information: "and because in motherboard the monitor must be connected to the card in first slot (which with 16 PCIe-Lanes), then I have: 16x-GeForce, 16x-Quadro K4000 and 8x-Quadro K2000"

Well fortunately it's not true (or at least, is not what is reported in the [manual of your motherboad](http://dl.msi.com/download_files/mnu_exe/E7736v1.0.zip)):

[image: lower part of pag 18 of the manual of the motherboard]

So the correct place to attach the monitor to is to slot PCI_E6, the 8x one... good luck swapping cards.

Congrats for your question being so precise - that's helped a lot (note - still don't know if it solve... keep us informed!).

Comment: @Robert Crovella  A small clarification: because P2P is possible only in TCC-mode, but TCC-mode does not support video output to monitor (as I know), and because in motherboard the monitor must be connected to the card in first slot (which with 16 PCIe-Lanes), then I have: 16x-GeForce, 16x-Quadro K4000 and 8x-Quadro K2000. And note that, if I try to copy data by using DMA-controller: cudaMemcpy(gpu1, gpu0, default); then I do this successfuly and I get speed 3 GB/sec, that corresponds to PCIe gen2 8x (4GB/sec theoretically), ie direct copy. I compare array gpu0[] and gpu1[] - they are equal.

Comment: @Alex I have improved my answer with your further information... in my case I really had a frustrating experience, but the mobo was too old and the problem coming from non nvidia PCIe cards.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have the same thing written in the documentation. I have cards in PCI_E1, PCI_E4 and PCI_E6. But I have tried right now, connected the monitor to PCI_E6 - shows nothing, and shows only in PCI_E1.

Comment: it is possible you have to dig in the bios and tell to *him* which card to use (to the bios - note the manual is speaking of POST phase, that's the messages before) - the bios manual will help... bios version?