# Running an MS unittest that requires a GPU from TFS Build

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, gpu

We have a series of unit tests that require an NVidia GPU for execution.  These tests currently fail (I think) because TFSBuild runs as a windows service and Windows (Windows 7 and later) does not allow windows services to access GPUs.  Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the MS Test Execution Engine on a build server does run as a service (just like the MSBuild process) and that services by default cannot access the GPU because of the "Session 0 Isolation" concept that was introduced in Windows Vista.

From what I've researched the only official way to get around this is to purchase an Nvidia Tesla card and have it run in "Tesla Compute Cluster" (TCC) mode which allows services to access the GPU for computing (like CUDA).  There is indirect evidence that [some Quadro cards also support TCC mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321098/can-i-use-quadro-k4000-and-k2000-for-gpudirect-v2-peer-to-peer-p2p-communictat), but I have not found anything official stating which ones do.

I have a [question](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/771286/tcc-mode-gpu-for-tfs-build-server/) up on Nvidia's forums asking about an inexpensive card for this exact scenario but it does not have any replies as of yet.

EDIT:
I just acquired an Nvidia Quadro K2200 and can confirm that it does indeed support TCC mode and works great running CUDA Unit tests on my build server during the build process.